# Pin on google maps disappears when not hard coding the latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am currently trying to implement a piece of Google Maps which sets a pin on the place the IP address is coming from. I am using the geolocation tool from Javascript.

However, when I hard code lat & lng it works just fine, but when I try to get the coordinates the pin disappears

Here's my code that does work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  function initMap(position) {



    var location = {lat: 51.165691, lng: 10.451526};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: location,
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFlvIBD_3jTrQgDAyj9RMLOdR9cqYZoco&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the changed code, that does not work anymore:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  function initMap(position) {



    var location = {lat: 51.165691, lng: 10.451526};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition)
    } else {
      return "Not available";
    }

    var a = position.coords.latitude;
    var b = position.coords.longitude;


    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: {lat: a, lng: b},
      map: map
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFlvIBD_3jTrQgDAyj9RMLOdR9cqYZoco&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I got a question ban because my questions are not upvoted, but answered and some good discussion happens in the comments. But the stack exchange team told me to edit my questions to making them more clear, but they received answers so I think they were clear. I am not a native speaker so my English is not the best and I cant express myself that good. But they told me to edit them so they appear as new and can be upvoted. I don't see why that makes sense, but maybe it lifts my question ban if I get some upvoted on already solved questions, so please upvote if you don't mind.

Comment: What is the value of `position.coords.latitude` and `position.coords.longitude`?

Comment: it is number with the same style as the two numbers in the location variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the success callback for accessing the navigator position,
See the attached working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Simple Map</title>
  <style>
      * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
      height: 500px;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>

<script>
  function initMap(position) {



    var location = {lat: 51.165691, lng: 10.451526};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: location
    });
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos){
       var a = pos.coords.latitude;
       var b = pos.coords.longitude;
       var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: {lat: a, lng: b},
         map: map
       });
      });
    } else {
      return "Not available";
    }
  }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCFlvIBD_3jTrQgDAyj9RMLOdR9cqYZoco&callback=initMap"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just tried your solution but it still doesn't show the marker.. I am trying to solve this for like 3-4 hours now.. f*** :D

Comment: Maybe you need to allow your browser to share position?

Comment: Yeah I thought that too, but it is allowed, and I get the coordinates in plain text.. but the pin can’t „use“ then

Comment: The above code works for me, it shows the map on Europe and then it pins my location...